# Pentaho - "Put a file with FTP"

Tags: java, ftp, authorization, pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to set up an automation in Pentaho. 
The creation of the result works fine, but I seem to be stuck using the "Putting a File with FTP" module.

When I set up the File transfer Job the test connection works fine.
(Can't upload an image cause of rep??)

But when I run the job there seems to be an Error putting to FTP (Login authentication failed)
See Log:

```html
2015/03/03 11:33:42 - Spoon - Starting job...
2015/03/03 11:33:42 - Upload_test - Start of job execution
2015/03/03 11:33:42 - Upload_test - Starting entry [Put a file with FTP]
2015/03/03 11:33:42 - Put a file with FTP - Using PDIFTPClient override for exists() fix.
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : Error putting to FTP : Login authentication failed
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException: 530 Login authentication failed
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP -  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.validateReply(FTPControlSocket.java:1194)
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP -  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.password(FTPClient.java:1855)
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP -  at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.login(FTPClient.java:1777)
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.ftpput.JobEntryFTPPUT.execute(JobEntryFTPPUT.java:704)
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:716)
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:532)
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Put a file with FTP -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:424)
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Upload_test - Finished job entry [Put a file with FTP] (result=[false])
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Upload_test - Job execution finished
2015/03/03 11:33:45 - Spoon - Job has ended.
2015/03/03 11:42:00 - Spoon - Spoon
```

I configured an FTP account especially for that job, with all the necessary rights etc.
Anyone an idea?

Comment: if during test connection it is showing connection is ok then it has to work properly, have you specified your folder location properly where you have to put the file in remote directory tab?

Comment: Yes, destination folder is specified and works.
(As a matter-of-fact it's the users root directory on the server)

Comment: Hey Peeps, could it have something to do with JAVA version i've ste as JAVA_HOME parth?
I've already downgraded from SDK 1.8 to 1.7.
I'm using Penthaho 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it!

After a lot of troubleshooting and testing I've found what was wrong and as I alreeady began to suspect it's a bug in the "Put a file" module.
Using wireshark i was able to capture the "conversation" between spoon and ftp server and i noticed a big difference.

When using the Get File Using FTP the module send out the follwing request -> REQUEST USER PentaHo@mijnabb.be@ftp.mijnabb.be
When using the Put a File Using FTP the module send out the following -> REQUEST USER PentaHo@mijnabb.be
So without the @ftp.mijnabb.be

When i changed the USER in the Put a File module from PentaHo@mijnabb.be to PentaHo@mijnabb.be@ftp.mijnabb.be it worked !!!!

So i guess this is a bug in the 5.2 Pentaho Put a file module!